# Why are Redux actions implemented as functions?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm studying how Redux works, and there is something I can't fully understand.

Usually Redux actions are implemented as functions. For example:

```
const ACTION_INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT'
const increment = function(amount) {
   return {type: ACTION_INCREMENT, amount: amount}
}

store.dispatch(increment(2));
```

Why aren't action implemented as classes? I mean, I find more natural something like this:

```
class ActionIncrement {
    constructor(amount) {
      this.amount = amount;
    }
}

store.dispatch(new ActionIncrement(2));
```

It's very strange that nobody does this. Is there an issue with this approach I haven't seen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to are **action creators**, which are functions that return actions (JS objects).

Here are some disadvantages I can think of right now:

- Classes are syntactically more complex, leading to longer boilerplate code, more room for misuse/mistakes (eg. forgetting to assign a `type` property for the reducers to identify).
- Action creators are meant to be stateless. Using classes might lead to more misuse/misunderstanding. Granted, you can use `this` on functions as well, but that's less common (and not possible for functions declared with ES6 arrow syntax).
- It will be incompatible with many existing Redux libraries, such as [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). `redux-thunk` delays the dispatching of the action to the reducers, allowing asynchronous calls in action creators. For such libraries to support classes, all classes must agree to have a common async method that will be called and awaited. This leads to more boilerplate and room for misuse/mistakes.

Comment: But I don't understand why an action should have a type. There is no guarantee you'll use it to choose the reducer, no need of that.

Regarding the action creators to be stateless, Isn't it a constructor stateless? I haven't ever seen a statefull constructor, maybe factories, but not constructors. 

I don't know redux-thunk, I'll take a look when possible.

Maybe it has to do with serialization? Maybe middleware? I think I should play a litte bit more with React it to see if I get it.

Comment: If it doesn't have a type, how would the reducers decide whether they should respond to it? Do you want each reducer to use a different way to check whether the action is relevant to it?

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter by error and I was editing. 

You could use whatever to check if action is appropriate for you, for example:

reducers.find( (reducer) =>  action instanceof reducer.expectedAction).reduce(state, action);

Comment: Or you could have:

if(action.ammount > 50) return bigReducer(state,action)
else return littleReducer(state,action)

Comment: If you do `const instance = new ActionIncrement(2)`, then do some state mutation within `ActionIncrement` and then do `dispatch(instance)`, then it'll no longer be stateless. As for the custom reducer checking, you are unnecessarily complicating the whole thing and making your actions/reducers less predictable, and your project will be incompatible with other libraries. We limit actions to a standard shape/type so that different libraries can work together more easily with the given assumptions about the shape/type.

Comment: Ok for the limitations for compatibility, but you could also `var action = actionCreator('banana'); action.payload = 'potato'; store.dispatch(action)`, so I don't see and advantage with that.

Comment: Like what I mentioned in point 2 above, the tendency to mutate instance variables is higher when `class` is used. Also, most Redux guides encourage the use of ES6 arrow functions which cannot be abused to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest reading [the Motivation section](https://redux.js.org/introduction/motivation) in the documentation.

> Following in the steps of Flux, CQRS, and Event Sourcing, Redux
>   attempts to make state mutations predictable by imposing certain
>   restrictions on how and when updates can happen. These restrictions
>   are reflected in the three principles of Redux.

You could create Classes as they are just syntactic sugar for creating Objects, however, what would be the benefit of doing that over more explicit Object literal?

An action is a simple configuration object with no side-effects which gives a lot of benefits like time-travel and more predictable debugging which is one of the main advantages of using redux. Having Classes IMO besides introducing extra code could point people to creating some state-mutating functionalities.